# Traer valores de un arreglo

Tags: php, laravel-8, php8

Estoy tratando de traer los mensajes de validación del siguiente arreglo y el que necesito es el de errors ya que quiero desplegar esos mensajes al momento de enviar un formulario:

```
array:3 [
  0 => Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\Failure {#1542
    #row: 5
    #attribute: "apellido"
    #errors: array:1 [
      0 => "El campo apellido es requerido. Error correspondiente a la fila:"
    ]
    -values: array:28 [
      "nombre" => "Pual"
      "apellido" => null
      "identificacion" => null
      "direccion" => null
      "codigo_postal" => null
    ]
  }
  1 => Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\Failure {#1966
    #row: 5
    #attribute: "identificacion"
    #errors: array:1 [
      0 => "El identificacion es requerido. Error correspondiente a la fila:"
    ]
    -values: array:28 [
      "nombre" => "Pual"
      "apellido" => null
      "identificacion" => null
      "direccion" => null
      "codigo_postal" => null
    ]
  }
  2 => Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\Failure {#1969
    #row: 5
    #attribute: "direccion"
    #errors: array:1 [
      0 => "El campo direccion es requerido. Error correspondiente a la fila:"
    ]
    -values: array:28 [
      "nombre" => "Pual"
      "apellido" => null
      "identificacion" => null
      "direccion" => null
      "codigo_postal" => null
    ]
  }
]
```

Pero al momento de traer de esta forma los mensajes de error solo me trae el primer mensaje y lo que quiero es que me traiga todos los mensajes de error en un solo listado y no solo el primero.

```
$failures = $e->failures();
            dd($failures);
        
            foreach ($failures as $failure) {
                $errors[] = [
                    'row' => $failure->row(),
                    'attribute' => $failure->attribute(),
                    'errors' => $failure->errors(),
                ];
                return ['status' => false, 'message' => 'Solucione los errores de la fila' . ' ' . $failure->row(), 'validate' => $failure->errors(), 'model' => $failures];
            }
```

Agradezco su ayuda para poder solventar mi problema.

Comment: `$failures` debería ser un array de objetos del tipo error ([ver aquí](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html#gathering-all-failures-at-the-end)). ¿Qué es lo que quieres realmente? ¿Con qué fines? ¿Por qué pones un `return` dentro del `foreach`? ¿No estarás re-inventando la rueda?

Comment: Un `return` puesto dentro de un bucle hará que sólo se lea el primer elemento. ¿Eso es lo que quieres? Además, no se entiende bien qué es lo que quieres hacer ahí, parecería que intentas re-inventar la rueda.

Comment: El return me regresa los errores de validación, por ejemplo esto de aquí:
{"status":false,"message":"Solucione los errores de la fila 5","validate":["El campo apellido es requerido. Error correspondiente a la fila:"],"model":[{"row":5,"attribute":"apellido","errors":["El campo apellido es requerido. Error correspondiente a la fila:"],"values":{"nombre":"Pual","apellido":null,"identificacion":null,"direccion":null,"codigo_postal":null}}

Comment: No, no te regresa ***los*** errores de validación, te regresa ***un*** error solamente, dado que haces `return` dentro del bucle. Además, como te dije anteriormente, los errores están ya todos en `$failures`, explica qué es lo que quieres, pues no se entiende. Si es posible, pon un ejemplo del resultado final esperado.

Comment: Al momento de traer los mensajes de errores en pantalla utilizando $failures->errors(), solo me trae el primer mensaje que seria:
"El campo apellido es requerido. Error correspondiente a la fila:"

Comment: pero yo quiero traer todos los mensajes de error para que al momento de que se vayan a registrar usuarios puedan ver todos los errores que tienen

Comment: Pues debes declarar alguna estructura (array u otra) fuera del `foreach`, luego, llenarla dentro del `foreach` con los datos que quieres devolver y fuera del `forearch` hacer un `return` de esa estructura. Algo así: `$mData=array(); foreach (...) { //aquí llenar $mData }  return $mData;`